# Algorithm to find the minimum difference between sums of all elements in a row of a given matrix

Tags: java, algorithm

I have some matrix with L rows and S columns with positive integers. I can only exchange elements in the same column. The task is to create new matrix with those elements such that the difference between the max sum and min sum of elements in 2 rows is minimal.

I wrote a recursive algorithm which finds two elements (for example a and b) in max and min rows, then checks if `a-b>0 AND a-b<dif`  (dif is sum(max)-sum(min)) and swap those two numbers. But it doesn't work in many situations.

Need help with improving it or creating a new one. 
Thank you

Edit: Test data

[19890 18842 11844 17791 12777 14086 19299 16760 19914 18888 15248 17778 12000 15211 18838 18817 18477 15935 18209 15880 16943 12060 ;

14485 16416 13744 11812 10959 10356 11290 15521 19834 12831 15002 19950 11852 19357 19296 15602 13582 13279 15904 13415 17652 19882 ]

It's 2 rows, 22 columns. Answer: 0

One more example:

[ 665   424   543   268   998;

963   805   434   361   541;

880   653   671   454   966;

323   843   649   934   173;

696   341   269   681   130;

867   829   993   767   263]

It's 6 rows, 5 columns. Answer: 4

Comment: Have you got any test data where the best solution is known?

Comment: What is this supposed to be? Two rows? 22 columns? - Please edit your question.

Comment: What does max sum and min sum mean? Is max sum the maximum of the sums of individual rows?

Comment: Max sum means it's the maximum between all sums of individual rows. Same is for min sum

Comment: I doubt if there even exists a solution better than exponential time just for the case when there are only 2 rows in the matrix. I wonder how complex the algorithm for a matrix with more than 2 rows would be.